# Multi criteria filter in VBA (Not equal to)

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code in Blue prism for filtering in excel for multi criteria.
But i am not able to filter multi criteria for Not equal to scenario.

```
Dim wb As Object
Dim excel as Object
Dim range as Object

Try
wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
excel = wb.Application
range = excel.Range(FRange)

Dim listOfValues as Array
listOfValues = Split(FCriteria,";")


wb.worksheets(Worksheet).select
range.select
range.Autofilter(FCol,listOfValues,7)



Success = True

Catch e As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = e.Message
Finally
    wb = Nothing
End Try
```

Please help me tweaking the script

Comment: There is no `Catch`, `Exception`, `Finally` and `End Try` in VBA.

Comment: This is C# code

Comment: You could simply filter the whole collection in Blue Prism. by forming a filter expression which is calculated rom your criteria. Alternatively you could build a new VBO page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that there is no filter option to set a "negative list". You can specify either a (positive) list of values (this is what your code does so far, for this you have to set the `7` as third parameter), or you can give a maximum of 2 individual criteria (in Excel, choose "Custom Filter" to set them.

You should play with the filter directly in Excel and try to set it like you want. Once you are satisfied with it, clear the filter, record a macro and repeat the filtering. Go to the VBA editor and see what's in there. It is straightforward to translate this into C# code.

But:

> It's not possible to set any filtering by code (neither C# nor VBA) that you cannot set via the Excel GUI

Answer (score 0):

I would question what you are trying to do. Since you are using Blue Prism, you should be trying to access the underlying data in a BP Collection(VB DataTable), rather than applying a filter, which is a visual tool for humans to further play with the interface. The robot will still have to do something with the filtered data, and it far easier to write code to proceed with data during the loop.

Otherwise use the Filter Collection Page of the 'Utilities - Collection Manipulation' VBO to get a filtered collection.

Also you are using VBA Split function, when you should use Split in VB as a method of the String.

Try this for a new page in the 'Utilities - Collection Manipulation' VBO(untested):

```
Dim NewRow As DataRow
Collection_Out = Collection_In.Clone

Dim Select_Concat As String
Select_Concat = "NOT(" & fieldName & " = '" & [String].Join("' OR " & fieldName & " = '", FCriteria.Split(";"c)) & "')"

For Each parentRow As DataRow In Collection_In.Select(Select_Concat)
    NewRow = Collection_Out.NewRow
    For Each c As DataColumn In NewRow.Table.Columns
        NewRow(c.ColumnName) = parentRow(c.ColumnName)
    Next c
    Collection_Out.Rows.Add(NewRow)
Next parentRow

NewRow = Nothing
Collection_In = Nothing
```

Inputs: Collection_In(Collection), fieldName(Text), FCriteria(Text)

Outputs: Collection_Out(Collection)

You first need to get the entire range into an unfiltered Collection(which will be your Collection_In to this page, and then get the filtered Collection out....